# Android L - Floating Action Button (FAB)

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-design-library

Did Google already released a defined style or a component for this new circular FAB button or should I implement the design on my own?

The button is described here: [Google Design | Floating Action Buttons](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

**EDIT (05/2015): Check [Lukas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538439/1945040) / [Gabriele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548910/1945040) showing an easy way to implement it with the design support library.**

Comment: How can I add the material select effect on this button?

Comment: @Sandra This effect will be added automatically, when the background-attribute is set to a drawable of the type "ripple".

Comment: Aha, I did not know that, thx. And where should I create the ripple.xml, drawables I suppose...

Comment: There's no such method as setOutline()...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE**: there's now an official widget for FAB: FloatingActionButton, see Gabriele Mariotti reply for full information.

According to Adam Powell and Chet Haase they didn't create a widget for the FAB button cause it's a very easy component to reproduce.

There was a question in the Google IO 2014 speech "Google I/O 2014 - Material science: Developing Android applications with material design", at the end of the speech (at about 37:50) there was exactly that question, you can hear it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSH9aKXjgt8#t=2280

Chet Haase says there's a RoundedBitmapDrawable (I didn't check if that's the name) that should already do the job of defining the Outline.

But you can do it with your own drawable, set an Elevation to it and define an circle Outline programmatically.

This should give you the round button with shadow on L release.
But I think You'll have to build the Shadow pre-L on your own.

I should check the code for CardView to see how it reproduce the shadow pre-L. I'll probably do that, but do not have time now. If no one pops in with the details I'll do it after I've found the time to go and check it up.

EDIT:

Gabriele Mariotti (see his answer below, thank you) added some code to show you how to do it.

Thanks to @shomeser comments, he wrote a library to make the fab button:

https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button

To use it:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.3'
}
```

You can also read his answer to another question: [How can I add the new "Floating Action Button" between two widgets/layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts/25098626#25098626)

Comment: although this widget is very simple, I published library with this widget: `com.shamanland:fab:0.0.3`, check my post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25098626/1891118

Answer (score 57):

**UPDATED: 26/08/2021**

With the [**Material components for android**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) add to your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.x.x'
```

Then add in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_24"/>
```

And use it:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
    (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);    
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle the click.
    }
});
```

If you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme your FAB will inherit the material style. Otherwise just apply the style `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    ../>
```

More [info here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/).

---

With **Jetpack compose** `1.0.x` use:

```
//Simple FAB
FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /* .. */ } ) {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"contentDescription")
}

//FAB custom color
FloatingActionButton(
    onClick = { /* .. */ },
    backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
    contentColor = Color.White
){
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"contentDescription")
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATED: 30/05/2015 with the official Design Support Library**

There an official widget now.

Just add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Add this view to your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```

And use it:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //TODO
            }
        });
```

Documentation [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html).

---

**UPDATED: 02/12/2014 with Android 5 code**

Also you can add and **stateListAnimator** to your Button:

```
<Button
 android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
/>
```

Where anim.xml is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="@dimen/button_elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_press_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="@dimen/button_press_elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Dimens.xml is

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_size">56dp</dimen>
 
    <dimen name="button_elevation">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_press_elevation">4dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Check the Daniele's answer.**

About Outline mentioned by Daniele.
Add the **elevation** attribute to your Button, and set the **Outline** via code:

```
   <ImageButton
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />
```

About Outline:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutfab);
        
        //Outline: OLD METHOD IN L-PREVIEW
        //int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
        //Outline outline = new Outline();
        //outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
        //findViewById(R.id.fab).setOutline(outline);

        Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        ViewOutlineProvider viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
           @Override
           public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
              // Or read size directly from the view's width/height
              int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
              outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
           }
        };
        fab.setOutlineProvider(viewOutlineProvider);
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I'm getting better on android l. But I got one question, what does this "stateListAnimator" do? I implemented it but actually saw no change, is it for customizing the "ripple" effect?

Comment: @theyanu The stateListAnimator provides the Z-animation based on button state.

Comment: FYI, if you use a `stateListAnimator` to adjust the z-translation (like in this answer), you do not need to specify an `elevation`. Adding an `elevation` in such a case will make the animation less obvious as the created shadow will always be visible, whatever state the button is in (at least in the Preview version of Android-L).

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti seems there is no method called setOutline

Comment: @DineshAnandan This method was used in android Preview. Now the code is different. I've updated the answer with the new code.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti got oval shape in ImageButton but the shadow is not visible same on cardview. Is there any issue from my side?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i have fixed my shadow issue. Here you can find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/27653781/1394139

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti FAB not showing fully in lollipop(Moto G). Image link http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmR0f.png

Comment: For others, to set color: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32031019/2901207 and to get it to the bottom. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31213989/2901207

Answer (score 21):

**Google now provides an official library**, called design library, **containing the Fab Button**. Just add the following Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Afterwards you can use the fab button like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

More information can be found in their announcement

http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

or on the javadoc page

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Answer (score 7):

Since Labels FAB feature (like in Evernote or Inbox apps) was added to this awesome [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) feel free to use it:

Gradle dependency:

```
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
```

Layout.xml:

```
     <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action B"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

menu_labels_style.xml:

```
    <style name="menu_labels_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

fab_label_background.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/black_semi_transparent"/>
    <padding
        android:left="16dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @Roman I am using this library only. But, I am not able to get the ripple by the method you suggested here. Please give some inputs.