# [Android L]Android Material circular button

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vvPa.jpg[image: Android L]

So, how would someone go about implementing the circular button that is showcased in android L? Also what is the technical name of the the circular button, XML code would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The button is called a FAB(Floating Action Button), it's quite simple to make.

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutfab);

        //Outline
        int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
        Outline outline = new Outline();
        outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOutline(outline);
    }

}
```

anim.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="@dimen/button_elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_press_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="@dimen/button_press_elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_size">56dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="button_elevation">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_press_elevation">4dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and your layout file to define the FAB button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally the ripple affect when you press the button.
ripple.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Enjoy your new FAB. Please keep in mind this is for android L only!

**EDIT**
This has been updated at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548910/4352176

Comment: Hopefully there will be a compatibility library released by Google when Android L will be out there!

Comment: Did anybody try with alternative drawable for the ripple.xml, for pre L versions? I have a problem when I define drawable and drawable-v21 folder.. In drawable I use shape and drawable-21 I use ripple, but my ripple.xml for L never shows up on L versions...

Comment: Hello Sandra,
The Preview SDK Released by Google is in no means meant for production, if you manage to enable android L themes/features in previous versions of android it would be very quick and dirty/hackish methods. Of course it's up to you if you want to implement unfinished APIs. When I started developing my app I was very exited to use the new APIs, thought through my experience with the app, I had to revert back to lower APIs because android L is not ready yet. I recommend following Google's design guidelines [link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

Comment: Just implement Google's design guidelines for material, but don't use the new API's yet. I advise everybody to withhold using API 20, until the API is fully ready for production. Anyhow I'm pretty sure Google released the preview SDK so developers could get a taste of what is coming up. I hope I could help. -Monkey

Comment: What if I want that the entire button would be a circular drawable (the bitmap itself is a circle) that has a ripple ?

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer and keeping your post up-to-date.

Answer (score 14):

There is a easier and for all version (v7) way:

```
<ImageButton style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/OkBt"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_return_black_36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
```

Look at style="@style/AppTheme"
The style that I have set for old version is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

For Android lollipop is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

The shape drawable for circle is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#81D4FA"/>
</shape>
```

It works fine for all android version, it make automatically the circle shadow in Lollipop.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define another drawable for it. It is quite simple actually, but undocumented.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

I got this from here: https://github.com/romainguy/google-io-2014/blob/7c174c7901d8cd2601807dcd17f3df7ed88fbee9/app/src/main/res/drawable/info_background.xml

Don't forget to set the elevation and the outline