# Android material design buttons - Pre lollipop

Tags: android, button, material-design

How do I implement the "raised button" and the "flat button" as described in google's material design guidelines?

---

> Raised buttons add dimension to mostly flat layouts. They emphasize >
>   functions on busy or wide spaces.

[image: raised buttons]

---

> Use flat buttons for toolbars and dialogs to avoid excessive layering.

[image: flat buttons]

Source: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html

Comment: Best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color/27316880#27316880

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles

Comment: Perhaps this should be a duplicate (I'm not clear). But this close reason is just wrong.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

*This requires Android 5.0*

**Raised Button**

Inherit your button style from Widget.Material.Button, and the standard elevation and raising action will automatically be applied.

```
<style name="Your.Button" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/raised_button_background</item>
</style>
```

Then you need to create a `raised_button_background.xml` file with your button's background color inside a ripple tag:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@color/button_color"/>
</ripple>
```

**Flat Button**

Edit: Instead of my previous advice for flat buttons, you should instead use follow the advice given by Stephen Kaiser below:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DONE"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
/>
```

Edit: If you are using Support Library, you can achieve the same result on Pre-Lollipop devices by using `style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`. (notice the absence of `android:`) The above example then becomes

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DONE"
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for this late answer. Is there a way to achieve the same result with Support Library? I inherited my theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and in Android Studio I can see the raised but I want, but when I run the app on my phone (api 17) I see the usual button

Comment: Sorry, ripple effects and elevation aren't supported in the support library. What I'd recommend doing is using flat buttons with the same color styles pre 5.0 and having v21 resource files so 5.0+ will be able to use the additional effects.

If you still want to use ripple effects, there are a few libraries that will add it, and you can manually add shadow effects to buttons to give the "raised" effect, but it would be a lot of work to get the raising/lowering animation on button press.

Ripple effect libraries:
https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView

Comment: Any way of making the raised-button style work on pre-lollipop? Even a fake style?

Comment: Disabled/Enabled states look the same. How to fix that?

Comment: Why doesn't the flat (borderless) button pull the accent color style when using material design?  Better to use buttonBarButtonStyle?

Comment: @lostintranslation Because in the AppCompat Base Theme the `borderlessButtonStyle` is set to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless`.  If you want it to pull the accent color, set the `borderlessButtonStyle` in your Theme to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored`.

Answer (score 83):

In order to implement the flat buttons, you could just add `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`.

Example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DONE"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    />
```

[Here's the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle) for the attribute.

Comment: Fantastic, and it supports back to API level 11.

Comment: @StephenKaiser How about the raised buttons?

Comment: `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` when using the AppCompat library

Answer (score 4):

You can use [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). It's third party library.

This is a library with components of Android L to you use in android 2.2
If you want use this library, you only have to download MaterialDesign project, import it into your workspace and add the project as a library in your android project settings.

Answer (score 2):

I use this as a background for a button with AppCompat and it depicts a raised button (with ripples n all), hope it helps.

**myRaisedButton.xml** - inside the `drawable` folder:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/yourColor"/>
            <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</resources>
```

**styles.xml (v21)**:

```
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
```

**layout.xml**:

```
...
android:background="@drawable/myRaisedButton"
```

Comment: Where do you use this xml? In drawable folder?

Comment: Yep,name it for example myRaisedButton.xml and access it from your layout with android:background="@drawable/myRaisedButton"

Comment: Thank you, it works! I had to delete the last line because I got an exception, how can I fix it? Sorry but I still have problems working with styles in xml

Comment: Yes I did that, but I get this exception if I don't delete the last line: "Binary XML file line #10: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable"

Comment: Hmm, please check my edited solution, and make sure that in your layout you have android:background=".." and not android:drawable=".."

Comment: Why did you make the styles.xml files to both point to the same style ("AppTheme.Base") ? I don't see the added functionality here...

Comment: This code generates an exception and does not create a raised button.

Comment: This code is working great with `appcompat-v7:23.4.0` library.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a material compatibility library. The button class is there and supports animated shadows and the touch ripple. Maybe you will find it useful. Here's the [link](https://androidreclib.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Man, this is awesome. How to include your aar lib via gradle ?

Comment: I wonder, how stable is it for using in real-life app ? did you have any crashes related to buttons : shadows/ripples? Thanks

Comment: I'm testing it on real project and doing my best to make it work. The library is under heavy developement, I'm trying to fix all reported bugs in 24h. In most cases the library doesn't crash, but rather produce animation glitches or just lag. For now two biggest issues are 1. lack of rendering thread (introduced in Lollipop) and 2. compatibility with all GPUs and UIs (for example TouchWiz used in Galaxy series).

If You have any other questions, You'd like to ask for a feature or report a bug, feel free to contact me. I've just updated the 'About' page on my blog to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

For a description of how to do this using the appcompat libray, check my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696134/1932522

This will show how to make use of the raised and flat buttons for both Android 5.0 and earlier (up to API level 11)!

Comment: style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"  is not an appCompat style. Your answer is valid only for API > 11

Answer (score 1):

You asked for **material design buttons Library** - **you got it** - https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add a bottom margin to your button, in order to be able to see the raised-button shadow effect:

```
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
<item name="android:elevation">1dp</item>
```