# Are there any official APIs/Samples/Tutorials for implementing the new Material-Design-guidelines?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

### Background

Google has recently added a lot of guidelines for designers ([**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)), including plenty of animations of how things can work.

### The problem

As I've read the guidelines, I decided to try out the new design, and use the support library.

Sadly, for many (or maybe all?) of them, I can't find out how to implement them using the official APIs that Google has given.

For example, I've tried to find out how they've implemented this cool scrolling effect called "Flexible space with image" (taken from [**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling)) : [**link**](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWZ1F2b1pUOGFiZHc/patterns-scrollingtech-scrolling-070801_Flexible_Space_with_Image_xhdpi_002.webm) . However, no matter where I search, the only thing I find is of third party libraries (like [**this one**](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)).

Another example is the way to create a Material-design raised button style (posted about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26983943/))

### What I've found

I've found only tiny snippets (and more guidelines) of very specific elements, on the android developers blog, for example [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html) and [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html) , but that's not nearly enough for using it, let alone support pre-Lollipop versions of Android (and that's most of the devices right now).

I've also found [**this documentation**](http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html) , but again, it lacks a lot of explanations to what is shown on the designers' website ([**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)).

### The question

Are there any APIs/Samples/Tutorials for any of the new Material design guidelines?

Anything other than what I've found?

Is it possible the support library barely supports the new design? I couldn't even find dialogs support and Prefereces in it, so I made something (based on someone else's library) [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialStuffLibrary) ...

It's just really weird that there are so many animations examples, but no actual code to try and use for best practice...

Comment: Your question only has lot of info than any answer could give ;-)

Comment: I see you've already found one sample app, but this one looks promising too. Perhaps there's more you could glean from Mike?

https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase

Comment: @user1190941 The library's sample doesn't seem to follow the guidelines, though it is quite cool: https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase/issues/8

Answer (score 8):

While the new API provides some new UI elements like  like CardView (that have been already included in  the support library) there are no new specific APIs for material animations, those animations abilities already exist in the current API.

The Material theme does provide default animations and activity transitions, however you need to do the rest by your self and as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html).

So long story short, while the new Android API 21 came with new components, you will still have to implement the majority of the design by your self.

Comment: What I've shown is also the floating button which scrolls and change its visibility based on the scrolling location, together with parallax effect of the image. It's not only the animation. Also, the animation seem to be only supported on API21, but I can't find if there is a support for older APIs.

Answer (score 4):

The new API's provide recylerview, cardview and many design API's and also backward support using appcompact v7 libraries.

for design specifications :- [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

Here are some options where you can learn material-design API's and implement them

1. if you are like me who enjoy watching videos than studying, here is a great source for you :- [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD) he is the best and i follow this playlist. still every week 2-4 videos will be added to playlist.
2. Google Developers: [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html) (they are the creaters)
3. Other website :- [TreyRobinson](http://treyrobinson.net/blog/)

But i recomend you using the 1st or 2nd option for learning.

Some great Source which i use to make my material design apps:

1. to select primarycolor,....etc : [Here](http://www.materialpalette.com/blue/amber)
2. to set an accent color : [Here](http://coolors.co/93032e-c69f89-3f51b5-84894a-034c3c) set primary color in middle lock it and press spacebar to load next set of accent colors.

Answer (score 2):

Hi here the url I found when I googled *"android lollipop apps github"*
https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase

I've used Android Studio 1.0 to git clone the source code, try it its fun