# Dependencies for Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

On the Material Design training page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html) it says that there are two dependencies and Prerequisites (1) Android 5.0 (api level 21) and (2) Android Studio 0.8.  Does this mean I can no longer use Eclipse to write Material Design apps for Android 5,0 and above??
thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is nothing impossible, but:

**1. No more support for ADT in Eclipse**

**2. Android Studio makes development easier**

I really understand you. I used Eclipse like you and decided to use Android Studio after release v. 1.0

It was not easy and I cant figure out how to do simplest things, but there is Google and a lot of answers here on StackOverflow.

I cant say that Android Studio is ideal, it has it's own '*features*'. Just Android Studio annoys less than Eclipse + ADT ))

For Material Design you can use this my answer - [Android Material Design Button Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles/27927003#27927003)

.

Hope this answer will help :)