# Android button default background

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-styles

I know that I can set the `background` of my `button` by using a `custom drawable` like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I also know how to set that.

But my real question is: how do I get the look and feel of a default material design button in just a different color, I can't seem to find the default style of it in the Android source.

Comment: What about this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` as a Button's style. This will give you a flat style look and will work on any pre-lollipop devices too.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle

If you are not interesed in backward compactibility then use can use the **Raised Button** which has the ripple effect and requires a device running 5.0

```
<style name="Your.Button" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/raised_background</item>
</style>
```

raised_background.xml

```
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:drawable="@color/button_color"/>
    </ripple>
```