# Material Theme in Xamarin.Form element

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

In my application, the AppCompat Theme is working fine created using [steps here](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/). I want to apply [RaisedButton](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) color in Xamarin.Forms Button. For this I have tried following:

- Added style in `MyApplication.Droid > Resources > Values> style.xml` [refering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles) as:

  `<style name="MyRaisedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"></style>`
- Added a button in MyApplication.Shared Portable form library in view MyView.xaml:

  `<Button Style="{StaticResource MyRaisedButton}" Text="Raised Button" />`

But its not working. As these two files (MyView.xaml and style.xml) are in different projects.  How can I add buttons in Xamarin.Forms with `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a custom `ButtonRenderer` added to your `Xamarin.Android` project:

[image]

```
new Button {
    WidthRequest = 50,
    Text = "Button"
},
new RaisedButton {
    WidthRequest = 50,
    Text = "RaisedButton"
}
```

#### `layout/raisedbutton.axml` (customize to your liking)

Note: Link it to a `style` id if desired and edit your `style.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/raisedbutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="StackOverflow"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

---

#### `RaisedButton.cs` (In PCL project):

---

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MaterialDesignButton
{
    public class RaisedButton : Button
    {
    }
}
```

---

#### `RaisedButtonRender.cs` (In Android project)

---

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using MaterialDesignButton;
using MaterialDesignButton.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RaisedButton), typeof(RaisedButtonRender))]
namespace MaterialDesignButton.Droid
{
    public class RaisedButtonRender : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var raisedButton = (Android.Widget.Button)Inflate(Context, Resource.Layout.raisedbutton, null);

                //Additional code: To make it generic               
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    raisedButton.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
                    raisedButton.Click += (s, ar) =>
                    {
                        if (e.NewElement.Command.CanExecute(null))
                        {
                            e.NewElement.Command.Execute(null);
                        }
                    };
                }

                SetNativeControl(raisedButton);
            }
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: This will replace all buttons in app with RaisedButton and I need to use this style for specific once.

Comment: @Vishnu No it would not. you registering `CustomButtonRenderer` for your `Xamarin.Form` `Button` subclass only

Comment: I tried this solution, creating `class RaisedButton:Xamarin.Forms.Button` and then adding a custom renderer in .Droid project with following code. There is RunTime error in below line, I may be missing some reference:

`button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Colored);`

Exception occurred:

`Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: @Vishnu I stripped down a version that I am using and updated the answer

Comment: @SushilHangover Can you please provide the reference for Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored list?

Comment: @Vishnu Reference:  `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` would be in `Xamarin.Android.v7.AppCompat`

Comment: @SushilHangover, sorry, I was asking if any reference link on Google/SO/Xamarin is there for this list values like `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`

Comment: @Vishnu :-) Ok, for a master listing of IDs for `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style` I use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html It is easy to remove the "_" from google's constants to get the C# style name... Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @SushilHangover, Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @Vishnu Great, happy coding :-)