# Remove margin from Android buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-theme

How can I remove the default margin Android buttons are using? I want the buttons to have full width (no space at all between the edge of the screen and the button) and no space between them. I am not setting any padding but they seem to have one.

I am using "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" as my app theme parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot showing the default margin android buttons have]

Comment: That is coming from the button backgrounds, most likely.

Comment: Did you use one of the provided solutions for this?

Comment: Tried them but they do not work as I wanted them. I ended using a custom ripple effect as background from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26349261/2456568

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The default button comes with margins. Set a button property like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
```

Do the same for the left, right, and bottom margins. Or define a new drawable with these parameters:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorButtonGray"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

The custom shape will not have any built in margins.

Answer (score 1):

Use as below in the button xml, then change the other features this changes to how you want them displayed.

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use 
android:minHeight=0
android:minWidth=0 to remove extra marging from button.

Comment: That is used to remove padding, not margin.