# Button styles in Android

Tags: android, button, android-xml

When I place a button in a layout, it has a standard gray background. However I want to make it more like the kind of button you see in the Dialogs where it's a background-less button (e.g. the white buttons with text).

Like this

[image]

Not like this... not like this...

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I just stumbled on it and have the answer (or at least I think), I really don't know if that's the best approach, but it should do the job.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The trick here is the `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored`. Also see this answer, it explains a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/1920068

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a TextView instead, and put a click effect with the background:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#23ac29"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```