# Setting perfectly circular rounded corners on a MaterialButton in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android, materialbutton

So I have been trying to find a way to make a `MaterialButton` from the Material Components library have perfectly rounded corners. What I mean by this is effectively they have a corner size of 50% the height of the button.

In some of the [documentation](https://material.io/design/shape/applying-shape-to-ui.html#shape-attributes) it indicates that this should be possible with the quote below.

> Shape size can be determined using a value that is either absolute or a percentage.

I have a couple of working solutions, firstly measuring the view and setting the corner size that way, but then I discovered that the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` uses a `RelativeCornerSize` object.

However, I still cannot find a solution in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.50"
    .../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.50" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

You can use an absolute or a percentage value.

[image]

Comment: This works great thank you, for some reason this does not display at all in the layout preview but works at runtime, so I think I discarded a similar solution too quickly!

Comment: If it have help you drop a upvote as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are specific commands with Material Design.

I could not explain it better than this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155799/13826785)

It works with Android Studio 3.1 or higher

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not see however any mention of setting corner radius as a percentage? They seem to still use hard coded values.

Comment: Are you using Kotlin or Java?

Comment: Kotlin, although I am comfortable with both!

Comment: Kotlin has its own function I believe to use percentage. Check this out: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/foundation/shape/corner/RoundedCornerShape