# Why button does not have material touch feedback?

Tags: android, android-view, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I am working on android application and using material design.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".registration.RegistrationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>

    <!-- to change back button color to white -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_medium</item>
</style>
```

activity_registration.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_view_padding_right"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_view_padding_left"
    android:text="@string/registration_sign_up"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_registration_business_state" />
```

RegistrationActivity.kt

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)
    }
}
```

[image]

Does anyone know why material design background color and feedback color is not setting on button ?

Comment: set parent `parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`android:theme`** instead of **`android:style`** .

At first Set your Button Parent `parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button`

Don't

```
style="@style/RobotoButtonStyle"
```

Do

```
android:theme="@style/RobotoButtonStyle"
```

Courtesy goes to **[Android Material Design Button Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/3395198)** .

**For a specific button:**

If you need to change the style of a specific button, you can define a new style, inheriting one of the parent styles described above. In the example below I just changed the background and font colors:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/Red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

Then you just need to apply this new style on the button with:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
```

Comment: I don't want to set theme on specific buttons, I want it for whole app so I have this https://pastebin.com/RGPfSpTg but i dont know why it not setting colorAccent to button

Comment: @Nancy Madam , http://manuel-ohlendorf.de/blog/2015/09/03/material-design-buttons-with-appcompat/

Comment: @Nancy Set the parent style for your button to `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"`

Comment: @Journey Isn't already there  `<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_regular</item>
    </style>` i know I am missing silly thing :(

Comment: I guess sloppy mistake coming .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya your solution is working `<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_normal</item>` it sets color but I want color with font too and it should be for entire app, I dont want to set on specific buttons.

Comment: I understand your problem .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you so much uff my mind is not working i think :P my bad

Comment: @Nancy Mam, Whats the way ? Share us

Comment: Just added `<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_light</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>` and `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>`

Comment: @Nancy Mam ,  I already told you sloppy mistake coming ..Hahahaha. by the by Happy coding .

Comment: can we set button height also in styles.xml ?

Comment: @Nancy `<item name="android:minHeight">20dp</item>`

Answer (score 1):

**(Works with the Support Library v7)**
Ok, simply replace

```
<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_medium</item>
</style>
```

with

```
<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/Accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_medium</item>
</style>
```

**Because**, you already have set `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>` in your `AppTheme` and from your Manifest the application is using the `AppTheme` which means every buttons in your application now takes the `RobotoButtonStyle`.