# How to make ConstraintLayout (androidx.constraintlayout.widget) work with MaterialButton (com.google.android.material.button)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

**Problem statement**

I am using `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` inside `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` where the constraint layout cannot deploy or detect the constraints of the `material button`.

**Code**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.screens.VeritasFolderReadSelectionScreen">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/folderSelectToolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/startGrad"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folderSelectMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Select folders you want PeerPots to read"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/folderSelectToolbar"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/folderRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/folderSelectMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <!-- Following code not working -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/folderViewButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

*Material button not visible*

**UPDATED**

**The error thrown while rendering**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException@207d8929     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor226.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
>     at
>   android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
>     at
>   android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
>     at
>   android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
>     at
>   android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
>     at
>   android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
>     at
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
>     at
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
>     at
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator.pulseAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1490)
>     at android.animation.AnimatorSet.pulseFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1163)
>     at
>   android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1146)
>     at
>   android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1046)
>     at
>   android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please show all code in layout file

Comment: Why is there a list there? It's not in your xml code! My assumption is that the list/recyclerview hides your button

Comment: Updated the code with full code

Comment: Have you synced the project properly? try once again and then check.

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately the reason of error or the solution is different and happens in rare and specific cases. I have provided the reason and solution below.

Comment: post build.gradle here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the code in other computers the reasons of the error found are-

1. **System support lack** - The system used for coding was not able to provide enough resources to render the views efficiently and for which the preview does not work.
2. **Android Studio efficiency** - On low capacity systems Android Studio cannot manage dependencies well while rendering and thus throws the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException`

**Solution**

1. **Optimal solution** - Use the recommended system configuration as per documentation.
2. **Ostrich solution** - Run the app every-time a change is made on the UI to see how it really works without depending on the *Preview*

Answer (score 1):

I have verified everything looks good and its working as well. As you can see in the attached image it's your above-mentioned code.

[image]

Please make sure you added the dependency into your gradle file. If yes, then there may be some issue in **some more properly working code here** which is overlap on the button. So you need to check in that code.

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

[image]

Comment: Updated the full code and also already using implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Comment: The answer is updated and it's also working fine. Have you run the code device or simulator? I hope it's working fine.

Comment: Your answer was right but unfortunately the reason of error or the solution is different and happens in rare and specific cases

Comment: add one more constraint in your recyclerview **app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/folderViewButton"** so that your button will not hide behind recyclerview. For the crash, you are facing checkout  link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111656/using-material-button-gives-classnotfound-runtime-error

Comment: @VijayPatole No need to add this because the button is in the last that means it will be always on the top of the layout.