# Icon is not appearing in the MaterialButton android studio

Tags: android, material-components-android

I'm adding `MaterialButton` to my android project and it only shows the text instead of both text and icons, here is  my code :

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#F8F8F8"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:text="@string/findTrans"
        app:icon="@drawable/white_bus_icon"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
         />
```

and here is how the buttons looks :

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and it shows an icon. double-check your `white_bus_icon`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111656/using-material-button-gives-classnotfound-runtime-error) I've found out that I just needed to add these lines to my app style file

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
```

And of course after having the dependencies added to your Gradle file :

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: thanks, i had the same problem, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line 
app:iconTint="@null" 
and try again