# change background color on android buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, background-color, android-button

I want to have my buttons to have the colors I specified, but otherwise still look and behave like the standard buttons. So I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles). I followed the advice given there, but the background color stays the standard grey. Any Idea where I´m going wrong?

In my styles.xml I put this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorButtonDark</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My colors are these:

```
<resources>
[...]
<color name="colorAccent">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorButtonDark">#300a03</color>
</resources>
```

And one example Button looks like this:

```
<Button
        android:text="exampleButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"/>
```

Comment: why the button's width and height are 0 ?

Comment: both are set to `match_constraint` in the Design Tab. Android Studio translates this to 0dp in the Text Tab. I guess the 0dp are overridden by the constraints.

Comment: Sorry i got this. Thanks for information and also you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` instead of `Button` in xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:text="exampleButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"`

use

`android:style="@style/AppTheme.Button"`.

EDIT1:

> Theme vs Style
>
> So what exactly is the difference? Well they are both
> declared in exactly the same way (which you already know), the
> difference comes in how they’re used.
>
> Themes are meant to be the global source of styling for your app. The
> new functionality doesn’t change that, it just allows you to tweak it
> per view.
>
> Styles are meant to be applied at a view level. Internally, when you
> set style on a View, the LayoutInflater will read the style and apply
> it to the AttributeSet before any explicit attributes (this allows you
> to override style values on a view).
>
> Values in an attribute set can reference values from the View’s theme.
>
> TL;DR: Themes are global, styles are local.

https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Comment: I don´t know about default behaviour, but it did not work, and in the link people are told explicitly to use `android:theme`.