# Android studio Button color not changing - Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, button, android-button, material-components-android

Here are my pics,
[It is the code in which i have written the color code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRX7.jpg)

[Here is android blueprint here the color doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLbKn.png)

I have tried many ways like adding through styles too it didn't work out.
I have also tried to change background tint but it doesn't help either.
how can i change the button color?
i have shared my code in pics above.
Help me to change color

Comment: Hey @Aryan What is your Theme. Did you set theme as per requirement. I am pretty sure the color of button is because of theme you set to app

Comment: check this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889.

Comment: @Venky i have a theme xml, but how can i set the theme can u please tell.
i am  a beginner so i don't know much,  please tell me

Comment: @AryanKalekar use `android:backgroundTint` instead of background

Comment: You can set a button theme in theme.xml and call where ever the button follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles

Comment: @Raghunandan i have tried nothing happens

Comment: Hi @Aryan, I think you are doing something wrong while uploading images. Please edit your question and make sure images are displayed right here, not the link to images... For reference, you can see your other question that I have edited.

Comment: Are you using a Material Components Theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just close the xml and reopen it. You will be able to find the defined color in your xml view. There is nothing to do with theme. Its just Android studio xml updation delay.

If it is not working then add below line to your Button tag

```
app:backgroundTint="your color code"
```

Comment: it doesn't help, i have tried it as well as when running an app. it shows the same color not what i have applied

Comment: OK. Share your styles file.

Comment: Check my answer again and try to apply the solution

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#156667"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

and apply it to your button's background in xml, you can change the color on `<solid android:color="yourColor"/>` there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a **`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** theme the `Button` is replaced with a `MaterialButton` and by default has the `backgroundTint` based on the **`colorPrimary`** defined in your app theme

Use the **`backgroundTint`** attribute to change your color.

You shouldn't use the `android:background` attribute to change the color but if you want to use it to define a custom background you have to avoid that the button is tinted using:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@null"/>
```

Also using the `android:background` attribute the `MaterialButton` doesn't use its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background. This means that features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded corners are ignored.

Comment: thanks sir for your detailed ans. i m sure next time i will be using this info