# Bottom Align Floating Action Button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to align to bottom right my FAB.

1. I tried with `android:gravity="bottom|right"`
2. When I try `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true`" `FAB` disappears
3. When I try `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lista_tiendas"` `FAB` disappears

It doesn't seem complicated but I just can't accomplish it

Any Ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista_tiendas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/spg_rosa"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/lista_tiendas"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

For `RelativeLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    ... />
```

---

For `CoordinatorLayout`, you should use `android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"`

---

For `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ... />
```

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609927/3922207) for more information.

Comment: yes, I corrected code format so  RelativeLayout appears! Tx

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks! Why doesn't LinearLayout work for a FAB?

Comment: Recommended is: android:layout_alignParentEnd = "true"

Comment: @Anggrayudi H  do you know how to do it with ConstraintLayout, then please tell.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH.Thank you so much i had issue with bottom sheet view when using coordinator layour but i found  your solution for relaive layout.wsted three days to fix this siue

Comment: i would like to use it for FAB on click i want to disable background fragment. but when i use clickable=true, fragment is not working ever though FAB is Closed. i just modified to a bit to use it in java class if fab is open clickable true or else false. its working grate thank you for  the solution

Answer (score 12):

Layout should be **RelativeLayout**. Try the next code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_list_form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_forms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_bar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_addc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wrapping the floating button in a linear layout is what did the trick for me. Otherwise it would ignore margins.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that FloatingActionButton isn't positioned correctly inside a RelativeLayout.

I changed RelativeLayout to FrameLayout, and problem solved!
Hope it helps!

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/spg_rosa"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and  `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the code to work by doing this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text"/>
```

However, it didn't work with `below` the `TextView` instead of above, I believe it could be a bug.

Comment: Ok, But I don't have a textview, I have a listview that take all the screen, so if I put it above, I will not have the desired position!

Answer (score 1):

Try

> android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

Answer (score 1):

**To Align The Button At Bottom and center of the Relative Layout**

Add these two in your floatingactionbutton container

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and the output will be:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMyPV.png)

Comment: The question requires aligning to the right bottom. Center Horizontal doesn't let that happen.