# Right and Bottom Constraint on FloatingActionButton makes it unseen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a `FloatingActionButton` inside a `ConstraintLayout`, like so:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_add_topic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                android:foregroundGravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_tooltip_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_tooltip_margin_top"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, as I inflate the layout on a `Fragment` with Android Databinding (on a Kotlin class), it does not appear.

I attempted to implement the solutions mentioned here, still inside the `ConstraintLayout` : [Bottom Align Floating Action Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769080/bottom-align-floating-action-button)

It appears just fine if I display it with Top and Left constraints.

Anything I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your layout includes these two constraints:

> ```
> app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
> ```

This will functionally position the bottom-right corner of your FAB at the top-left corner of the screen. In other words, you've constrained the FAB to be off-screen.

Chances are good that you meant you want the right of the FAB to be at the *right* of the screen, and the bottom of the FAB to be at the *bottom* of the screen. So use these instead:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: Have you set additional attributes to the FAB or the parent ConstraintLayout? Replacing the constraints alone does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Turns out I had a problem with a ViewPager whose bounds are way off the screen. I'll post a different question if someone hasn't already. Thank you @Ben P.

Comment: to support RTL use app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

Answer (score 2):

The `FloatingActionButton` can be aligned to all corners of the parent `ConstraintLayout`:

| FAB constraint relation | XML markup |
| --- | --- |
| top & start | `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` |
| top & end | `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` |
| bottom & start | `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` |
| bottom & end | `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` |

To evenly position it, use `layout_margin`:

```
android:layout_margin="24dp"
```