# BottomAppBar ignoring 'layout_gravity', always shown at top

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a `BottomAppBar` into my app and can't make the FAB or `BottomAppBar` display at the bottom.  Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".dashboard.DashboardActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar"/>

<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mtrl_bottomappbar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:fabAttached="true"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="12dp"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, this is what is being shown in the emulator:

[image]

How do I align it at the bottom?

Comment: Did any answer work for you?you are supposed to accept if it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConstraintLayout doesn't make use of layout_gravity.  Instead, use:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

without margin.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up wrapping my FAB and BottomAppBar in a CoordinatorLayout instead.  Using your snippet worked for the BottomAppBar but the FAB would not attach whatever I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it depends on your root layout too.
for ConstraintLayout try `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769080/bottom-align-floating-action-button) for other layouts too.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change the layout to LinearLayout and define orientation as vertical in it and then put your code in another LinearLayout in which you can make its marginTop as your requirements
just make these changes it should work fine

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".dashboard.DashboardActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

>

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp" //mark height accordingly
 >


  \\put your code here



</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

try this should work fine for you

Comment: don't post code blob as answer w/o explanation what you changed and why. It's pretty useless from educational PoV

Comment: Yeah I’m sorry man, I really don’t want to use a LinearLayout as my root layout...